# Sum of the digits of $2012^{2012}$ and sum of that sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I attempted to solve the following problem:

*Let $S_1$ be the sum of the digits of $2012^{2012}$ and $S_2$ be the sum of the digits of $S_1$. Find $S_1$ and $S_2$.*

Here is what I've got:

Let $n = 2012^{2012}$. Let $k_1$ be the number of digits of $n$. Let $k_2$ be the number of digits of $S_1$.

Finding the number of digits can be done by taking the "ceiling" term (or "floor" term and add $1$) of $\log_{10}n$, this gives:

$k_1=\left \lceil \log_{10}n \right \rceil = 6647$ and $k_2=\left \lceil \log_{10}S_1 \right \rceil$.

The idea I tried to use in order to calculate the sum of the digits is taking the sum of each $i$-th digit times the according power of $10$, for example for $2012$:

$2012= 2 \cdot 10^3+0 \cdot 10^2 + 1 \cdot 10^1 + 2 \cdot 10^0$.

For $S_1$ and $S_2$ this gives:

$S_1=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k_1-1} \lambda_i \cdot 10^i$ and $S_2=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k_2-1} \alpha_i \cdot 10^i$.

Then I tried to find a way to express the $\lambda_i$s and $\alpha_i$s, this is what i came up with:

$\lambda_i =\left \lfloor n \cdot 10^{-i} \mod 10 \right \rfloor ,\; i=0,\cdots,k-1$

$\alpha_i =\left \lfloor S_1 \cdot 10^{-i} \mod 10 \right \rfloor ,\; i=0,\cdots,k-1$.

Plugging it back in $S_1$ and $S_2$ gives:

$S_1=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k_1-1} \left \lfloor n\cdot10^{-i} \mod 10 \right \rfloor \cdot 10^i$

$S_2=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{k_2-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k_1-1}\left( \left\lfloor \left\lfloor n\cdot 10^{-i} \mod 10 \right\rfloor  \cdot 10^{i}\cdot 10^{-j}  \mod 10 \right\rfloor \cdot 10^j \right) $.

Thank you very much for reading this far, now I have a some questions!

Firstly is this even correct? And if it is, is there a smarter way to calculate $S_1$ and $S_2$ (because with this formulation it clearly isn't possible to calculate by hand, unless you have a lot (a lot) of time to spare) or calculating it will always require a computer?

Apologies for any maths, synthax or english errors!

Comment: In base 2012, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are $1$.

Comment: Simple arithmetic tells you that $S_2\in \{7,16,25,34\}$ but I don't see how to narrow that down without heavy labor, and the corresponding range for $S_1$ is not small.

Comment: @lulu, how do you find these ranges?

Comment: @lhf  Log's tell us that $n$ has $6647$ digits, so we know that $S_1 \leq 9*6647=59832$ which has 5 digits.  So we know that $S_2 \leq 9*5 =45$.  We also know that $n\equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, so lulu's list is the numbers congruent to $7 \mod{9}$ and less than 45.  (But I don't  know why 43 isn't in her list.)

Comment: @saulspatz  The last digit of $S_1$ isn't $6$.  But if I redo my calculations replacing $9$ with $4.5$ (assuming uniform distribution of digits) then I get $S_2 =22.5$.  So if this was multiple choice test, I'd pick $25$.

Comment: @lhf  Since there are $6647$ digits in $N$, we see that $S_1≤9\times 6647=59823$.  Thus $S_1$ has at most $5$ digits, and the first can not exceed $5$.  Thus $S_2≤5+4\times 9=41$.  As $S_1\equiv 7 \pmod 9$, we are done.

Comment: @B.Goddard  Since we know the first digit of $S_1$ is $≤5$ we must have $S_2≤5+4\times 9=41$.  You can tighten that up a bit, but not enough to eliminate $34$ as an option, at least not that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a hand accessible way to calculate these.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20digits%20of%202012%5E2012) gives $S_1=29383$ and from this it is easy to see $S_2=25$.  You have correctly noticed that the sum of digits operator works a lot like a logarithm, so it makes big numbers much smaller.  Usually when questions like this are asked there are enough sums taken (three in this case) that you can show the result has a single digit.  Then you use the fact that the remainder on division by $9$ is maintained by the sum of digits, so if you can find the value $\bmod 9$ you are done.  For this you would say
$$2012^{2012}\equiv 5^{2012} \pmod 9\\
5^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 9\\
5^{2012}=5^{6\cdot 305+2}\equiv 5^2\equiv 7 \pmod 9$$
which is well within hand calculation.

Comment: For $S_2$ given $S_3$ there are limited possibilities. I can see how they might be constrained, but not quite how to hit the exact value. I was surprised to be asked for $S_1$, because that is well beyond the range of obvious constraints, unless there is some really neat trick for this particular value.

Comment: @MarkBennet:  We could guess an approximate value for $S_1$ by taking the average digit to be $4.5$.  It is $4.42$ in fact.  From that we can guess that $S_2$ is $16,25, 34$ or just possibly $43$.  I don't see how to be sure which.  Certainly $25$ is closest to $4.5$ per digit of $S_1$